# Compact form for N iterations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to write the following in a compact form:

$p(A|x_1) \propto p(x_1|A)p(A) \propto p(x_1|1)p(A)$

$p(B|x_1) \propto p(x_1|A)p(B)\propto p(x_1|0)p(B)$

$p(C|x_1)\propto p(x_1|C)p(C)\propto p(x_1|0)p(C)$

$p(A|x_1,x_2)\propto p(x_1|A)p(x_2|A) p(A)\propto p(x_1|1) \cdot p(x_2|0) \cdot p(A)$

$p(B|x_1,x_2)\propto p(x_1|0) \cdot p(x_2|1) \cdot p(B)$

$p(C|x_1,x_2)\propto p(x_1|0) \cdot p(x_2|0) \cdot p(C)$

$p(A|x_1,x_2, x_3)\propto p(x_1|1) \cdot p(x_2|0) \cdot p(x_3|0)  \cdot p(A)$

$p(B|x_1,x_2, x_3)\propto p(x_1|0) \cdot p(x_2|1) \cdot p(x_3|0) \cdot p(B)$

$p(C|x_1,x_2, x_3)\propto p(x_1|0) \cdot p(x_2|0) \cdot p(x_3|1)  \cdot p(C)$

$p(A|x_1,x_2, x_3,x_4)\propto p(x_1|1) \cdot p(x_2|0) \cdot p(x_3|0) \cdot p(x_4|1)  \cdot p(A)$

$p(B|x_1,x_2, x_3,x_4)\propto p(x_1|0) \cdot p(x_2|1) \cdot p(x_3|0) \cdot p(x_4|0)  \cdot p(B)$

$p(C|x_1,x_2, x_3,x_4)\propto p(x_1|0) \cdot p(x_2|0) \cdot p(x_3|1)  \cdot p(x_4|0) \cdot p(C)$

...

I want to write it in compact form. Would it be something like that? How can I indicate the value of $m_j$ being 1 or 0?

$p(d|x1...x_N)\propto \prod_{i=1}^N p(x_i|m_i=m_j)\cdot p(d)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all there is no association of the letters $A,B,C$ with numbers, so we first define/rename: $A \equiv d_1, B \equiv d_2, C \equiv d_3$.

Next it seems (from pattern matching) that $d_1$ (i.e. $A$) is matched with $p(x_i|1)$ iff $i = 1, 4, 7, ...$, i.e. whenever $i = 1 \mod 3$.

Next we use a relatively standard shorthand called Kronecker delta: $\delta_{ij}$ has value $1$ if $i=j$, and value $0$ if $i \neq j$.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

So putting things together: $\forall N, \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3\}:$

$$p(d_i | x_1, ..., x_N) \propto p(d_i) \prod_{j=1}^N p(x_j | \delta_{(i \ \text{mod}\ 3)(j\ \text{mod}\ 3)}) $$

Instead of the delta, we can also use the indicator function / symbol.  I am not sure this is as standard, but one way I've seen is $\mathbf{1}[blah]$ has value $1$ if $blah$ is true and $0$ if $blah$ is false.  So we can replace $\delta_{(i \ \text{mod}\ 3)(j\ \text{mod}\ 3)}$ by $\mathbf{1}[i = j\ \text{mod}\ 3]$:

$$p(d_i | x_1, ..., x_N) \propto p(d_i) \prod_{j=1}^N p(x_j | \mathbf{1}[i = j\ \text{mod}\ 3]) $$

Are these roughly what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes! If I had to built a probabilistic graphical model, how would that be? I'm not sure how to put the leafs and the delta.

Comment: What do you mean by "graphical" model, and "leafs"?

Comment: Something like that: https://bit.ly/2JaHuQG. the graphic representation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with those...